# "GCP API keys hard-coded in the App's" warning on Oculus Store

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculusquest

We are using firebase plugin in Unity Project for the google sign in.

We are working with VR and Non-VR projects. We don't use the google signin for VR but its in our project.

We got warning in "GCP API keys hard-coded in the App's" while upload to oculus quest store.

If we removed the firebase plugin in our project, after we upload into store the warning is not showing.

What is the reason for the above warning. Give any suggestion to fix it.